# Ruby and bignum issue with OSX terminal

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal

I'm learning Ruby and am working through this problem on [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3). When I try to run my Ruby file through the terminal for the answer, it just stalls (no error message, but just comes up blank like its thinking). I'm assuming it's an issue with calculating such a large number.  I tried copying and pasting my code into repl.it, but came up with this error message:

> (eval):12: (eval):12: negative allocation size (or too big)
>   (NoMemoryError)

Is there any way around this through the terminal (or any other suggestions)? Thanks.

Edit (added in my code):

```
#3. Largest prime factor
#The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

#What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?



def largest_prime(num)
  all_primes = []
  (2...num).each do |p|
    if (num % p == 0) && (is_prime?(p))
      all_primes << p
    end
  end
  all_primes.sort!
  puts all_primes.last
end


def is_prime?(number)
  (2...number).each do |x|
    if number % x == 0
      return false
    else
      next
    end    
  end
  true
end

puts largest_prime(600851475143)
```

Comment: how about posting your code here?

Comment: Thanks Petey. I edited my question with my code pasted in.

Comment: its working. just alot of numbers to go through, `2...600851475143` is a pretty big range. Throw `puts "checking #{p}"` after your `(2...num).each` line and you will see what i mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind Project Euler is to build effective algorithms, otherwise the execution will just take too much time or resources - this is your case. Take a look at [primality_test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) wiki article and you'll understand, why you shouldn't check `(2...number)` and why `(2..Math.sqrt(num))` is enough. I didn't run your code, but suggest you to improve your `is_prime?` method first of all(by the way, you shouldn't prefix your method names with `is_` when you have question mark in the end):

```
def prime?(num)
  return false if num == 0 || num == 1
  (2..Math.sqrt(num).to_i).each do |i|
    return false if num % i == 0
  end
  true
end
```

It isn't MOST effective way of prime numbers detection, but its one of the simplest and effective enough for your needs.